# Eclipse error log

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running Windows 10 and I recently ran into a problem with opening Eclipse. Originally, I was unable to use the javac command on command prompt because of a message that said: "javac is not recognized as internal or external program". To fix this, I went into the environment variables and added the PATH variable, which was not there before, and made the address to the bin folder in my Java folder. This fixed that problem and allowed me to use javac and run my files, however, now I am unable to open Eclipse. Whenever I run Eclipse, The program starts to load then fails and refers me to the log. In the error log I get this:

[image]

So far, I deleted that PATH variable then retried Eclipse and an error message said it was unable to find a javaw.exe file. I found my java files and put the path to that file in my eclipse folder and tried eclipse again. This time, eclipse started to load but then failed and referred me back to the error log. It seems that eclipse is able to find the javaw.exe file but I'm not sure what else is wrong now.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use an older version of Eclipse with Java 9 - this won't work without modifications. Move to Eclipse Oxygen.2

Comment: Yeah, I reverted to Java 8 and it works. I deleted my PATH variable and if I put it back in I know I will get an error again with Eclipse, but I cannot use javac without that variable being specified. Do you know what path I should enter so that it won't interfere with Eclipse?

Comment: You can modify the 'eclipse.ini' to add a path to the Java that Eclipse should use (use the `-vm` option)

Comment: Can you update the OP with the **complete** versions of Eclipse and Java that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

My Eclipse and Java versions were not compatible. IF anyone else has this problem make sure of that first. After fixing this, I went to the PATH environment variable and I was able to add multiple paths, so I added both of these:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin
and 
C:\Program Files\eclipse\jre\bin

The first path is necessary to use javac from command prompt. The second address is necessary for eclipse to access the javaw.exe file.

Comment: But what was your full version of Eclipse?